# Replace protocol relative URLs with http://

Tags: php, regex, protocol-relative

I've got an app that loads a local file and appends downloaded HTML data. This data sometimes contains [protocol relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), basically `//domain.com/file` instead of `http://domain.com/file`. The upside is that this automatically chooses the appropriate protocol, which would be fine on web domains, but not when loaded locally – it then uses the `file://`-protocol.

Therefore I need to replace all occurrences of `attr="//domain.com/file"` with `attr="http://domain.com/file"` - essentially adding `http:` in front. The easiest is to do it in PHP I suppose, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_replace, if 'attr' is only inside tag:

```
$content = preg_replace('@(<.+?)(attr="//)(.*?>)@', '\\1attr="http://\\3', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** the `attr="//` text will not appear as a free text like `<p> ... attr="// ... </p>`

Using `str_replace`

```
$contents = str_replace('attr="//', 'attr="http://', $contents);
```

Using `preg_replace`

```
$contents = preg_replace('|attr="//|', 'attr="http://', $contents);
```

Comment: Thanks, I should probably have specified that the `attr` will be inside a tag.